# Oracle database links to grant/revoke roles

Tags: database, oracle, plsqldeveloper, sql-grant

I have a question about how to use database links in Oracle PL/SQL.  Let's say I have a database link (Database2) created in my current database, and I am using it to access a second database.  For example:

```
select *from CustomerTable@Database2;

Update CustomerTable@Database2
set Comment = 'Hello world!'
where CustomerID = 123;
```

These all work successfully.

But let's say I want to grant roles to or revoke roles from a user in Database2.  Can that be done through my database link?  If so, what is the syntax?

If I open a PL/SQL session in Database2, then the syntax would be:

```
REVOKE some_role FROM bsmith;

GRANT some_other_role TO rjones;
```

Is there any way to do this from my original database using my database link?

Comment: Why would you want to do DDL over the database link?  That's generally not allowed and is generally a bad idea.  You could create a stored procedure on Database2 that does whatever DDL you want and then grant the database link user execute access on that procedure.  Or you could get really tricky and schedule a job to run on database2 that would actually do the grants but that's a pretty complicated architecture.

Comment: I'm writing a stored procedure that will take some particular records and permissions from my production database and copy them down to either my development or test database.  I can copy the records no problem, but granting the permissions is turning out to be a lot trickier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do DDL over a DB Link by calling the DBMS_SQL package on the remote database:

```
declare
 v_cursor   NUMBER;
 v_ind        number;
 v_ret      varchar2(2000);
BEGIN
  v_cursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor@DB;
  dbms_sql.parse@DB(v_cursor, 'create sequence xyz_seq', dbms_sql.native);
  v_ind := dbms_sql.EXECUTE@DB( v_cursor );
end;
/
```

Comment: Good idea.  Thanks, Gary.

Comment: Or `dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@remotedb()` might be simpler (untested but I dimly recall using that 20 years ago).